# Reading and printing HTML from website hangs up

Tags: java, html

I've been working on some Java code in which a string is converted into a URL and then used to  download and output its corresponding URL.  Unfortunately, when I run the program, it just hangs up.  Does anyone have any suggestsion?

Note:  I've used import java.io.* and import java.net.*

```
public static boolean htmlOutput(String testURL) throws Exception {
    URL myPage2 = new URL(testURL); //converting String to URL
    System.out.println(myPage2);
    BufferedReader webInput2 = new BufferedReader( 
    new InputStreamReader(myPage2.openStream()));
    String individualLine=null; 
    String completeInput=null; 

    while ((individualLine = webInput2.readLine()) != null) {
        //System.out.println(inputLine);
        System.out.println(individualLine);
        completeInput=completeInput+individualLine;
    }//end while
    webInput2.close();
    return true;
}//end htmlOutput()
```

Comment: This would be an awful lot easier with `jSoup`.

Comment: What does debugging tell? Where does it hang?

Comment: How would you define "hangs up"?

Comment: Is there any error, or it just starts and then finishes before printing anythig?

Comment: Which testUrl have you used, I am able to run this program with http[colon][slash][slash]www[dot]google[dot]com as test url.

Comment: http://secreturl.com/Link/FullText/666?ResourceId=1195561&CIID=30420773&ECID=2457&UrlSource=EJS&Usage=ATOZ

Comment: When I say "hangs up", I mean that nothing happens.  The cursor just sits there, mocking me...  This happens immediately and there's no debugging information.

Comment: @eggHunter: I just tried your code, as is, with your example URL, and it works fine here. Maybe you have a firewall or something that prevents you from connecting to the URL.

Comment: I think the problem is in the while loop. You are trying to read webInput2 at the end of it, and until it is not null, you are printing individualLine. Could u try this: while ( webInput2.readLine() != null) { individualLine = webInput2.readLine(); Sysou(individiulLine) ... }

Comment: rats, didn't work.  I did a little testing and have come to the conclusion the issue lines within

Comment: rats, didn't work.  I did a little testing and have come to the conclusion the issue lines within      BufferedReader webInput2 = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(myPage2.openStream()));

Comment: @B.K.: the code as is is correct. Yours is not: it reads two lines at each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Though this answer helped the OP it is wrong. `HttpURLConnection` [**does** follow redirects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFollowRedirects%28boolean%29) so this could not be the OP 's problem. I will remove it as soon as the OP removes the accepted mark.]*

My guess is that you don't get anything back in the response stream because the page you are trying to connect sends you a redirect response (i.e. 302).

Try to verify that by reading the response code and iterate over the response headers. There should be a header named `Location` with a new url that you need to follow

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
int code = connection.getResponseCode();
Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields(); 

// iterate over the map and find new url
```

If you are having trouble getting the above snippet to work take a look at a [working example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-http-response-header-in-java/)

You could do yourself a favor and use a third party http client like [Apache Http client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html) that can handle redirects otherwise you should do this manually.

Comment: @eggHunter I am glad that it worked out for you. Please don't forget to accept the answer as correct :)

Comment: After some investigation I discovered my code does actually work but you were right in that there was a weird redirect built in.  I can still grab the page with the redirect with my code, the error laid within the String I was sending the method.  It had an awkward quotation mark in it.

Comment: @eggHunter Hmm actually we can't both be correct. As I see now `HttpURLConnection` can handle this by default. It has a method for `setFollowRedirects()` and should be able to get the html. Can you confirm that your original code works and the problem was with the url you were using? If yes I am going to delete my answer since it is wrong

Comment: @eggHunter Can you please unaccept this answer? The system does not let me to delete it as long as it is accepted